Log4Net not working on Windows Service Application
I have a console application in 1 project and a windows service application in a seperate project. Both applications create an instance of the same class and within that class I instantiate a custom "Logger" class, which I have built, which invokes the use of Log4Net.
The class that both applications creates an instance of has a constructor, which looks like this,
public MyClass()
{
    // Some stuff
    Logger = new Logger();
    Logger.WriteInfo("Receive() - Client and Processor have now been created");
}

Now the Logger class looks like this,
using System;
using log4net.Config;
using log4net;
using System.Reflection;
using log4net.Repository;
using log4net.Util;

namespace App.WindowsService
{
    public class Logger
    {
        private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Logger));
        public Logger()
        {
            var logRepository = LogManager.GetRepository(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()!);
            XmlConfigurator.Configure(logRepository, new FileInfo("log4net.config"));
        }

        public void WriteDebug(string Message)
        {
            log.Debug(Message);
        }

        public void WriteInfo(string Message)
        {
            log.Info(Message);
        }
        public void WriteWarning(string Message)
        {
            log.Warn(Message);
        }

        public void WriteError(string Message)
        {
            log.Error(Message);
        }

        public void WriteFatal(string Message)
        {
            log.Fatal(Message);
        }
    }
}

When the console application is run, the log file is created successfully in the same directory as where the console application is run from. However, when I run my service application both in debug mode and as an actual service, the log file is not created. I have tried adding the following lines into my Logger constructor,
string? workingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
LogManager.GetRepository().Name = $"{workingDirectory}\\Temp";
logRepository.Properties["LogFileLocation"] = $"{workingDirectory}";
logRepository.Properties["LogFileName"] = $"mylogfile";
XmlConfigurator.Configure(logRepository, new FileInfo("log4net.config"));

Along with adding the following into the log4net.config file that is output to the same directory as the application exe file,
<appender name="file" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="%property{LogFileLocation}\\%property{LogFileName}.log" />

Unfortunately this doesnt make any difference. I suspect this may require something to do with the Program.cs file in my service application project, which currently looks like this,
using App.WindowsService;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using static App.WindowsService.WindowsBackgroundService;

var builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddWindowsService(options =>
{
    options.ServiceName = ".NET My Service";
});

LoggerProviderOptions.RegisterProviderOptions<
    EventLogSettings, EventLogLoggerProvider>(builder.Services);

builder.Services.Configure<ConnectionConfiguration>(config =>builder.Configuration.GetSection(ConnectionConfiguration.Configuration!).Bind(config));
builder.Services.AddSingleton<MyClass>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<WindowsBackgroundService>();

var host = builder.Build();
host.Run();

Would anyone be able to shed any light as to what I would need to do here in order for my service application to be able to make additional use of Log4Net to log events into a file, which works for my console application?

Update:
This does not appear to be a permissions issue. The issue seems to be activating the configuration for Log4net. You can see below 2 instances of the Logger class being run, one from the console application and the other from the service application.
1)

You can see that logRepository.Configured is true here and in this instance the log file is created.
2)

You can see that logRepository.Configured is false here and in this instance the log file is not created.

The CurrentDirectory might not be what you expect. Did you try hard-coding a directory? Also: does the service's user account have the necessary permissions to write to the directory?

Unfortunately this doesnt appear to be a permissions issue on the folder itself. I have tried hardcoding an actual path to no avail. I have added some more information to the post, which I hope will help in diagnosing the problem

Have you also tried hardcoding the location of log4net.config?

After reading from this source here, I was able to get logging working! Turns out the service project needs sight of an "App.config" file that you may have to add manually to the project if there is not one there already and then add put the following content in,
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>

Once this was done, I still had a problem in that my Logger class was trying to locate the log4net.config file from the service application folder but in fact it was in the bin directory, which is where the application was being run from so I had to make a slight tweak to my Logger constructor as follows,
var logRepository = LogManager.GetRepository(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()!);
string? path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.Location);
XmlConfigurator.Configure(logRepository, new FileInfo($"{path}\\log4net.config"));

This has now resolved the issue!

AFAIK the first section (app.config) is not needed* but by enabling internal debugging it often shows you where the error is. The second part is the actual fix and if you delete the app.config the service should continue to work.
